# 802.11r roaming between OpenWRT device and KeeneticOS device

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, openwrt

I have TP-Link TL-WR741N (OpenWRT) and Keenetic Speedster (KeeneticOS)

How can I enable “Fast-Roaming” (802.11r) between these routers?

OpenWRT 802.11r settings:

> [image: OpenWRT 802.11r settings]

KeeneticOS 802.11r settings:

> [image: KeeneticOS 802.11r settings]

Comment: I've heard that the two-letter Mobility Domain ID from Keenetic can be converted into a four-symbol hexadecimal Mobility Domain ID for OpenWRT using a text to hex converter. However, the nature of the Mobility Domain key is still unclear to me.